# Sort DOM elements by Specific Child (no JQuery)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, dom, selectors-api

I'm specifically looking to sort this nodeList:

```
var liList = document.getElementsById("theOl").querySelectorAll(".theOl > li");
```

And sort it by a specific child:

```
liList[someIndex].querySelectorAll('a[href]')[0]
```

Basically, sort the entire node list alphabetically by the src of the a returned by querySelectorAll('a[src]'). Every item in the array will have this element. It will always return 1 element.

Comment: I think you should be sorting for 'a[href]' instead?

Comment: Of course sorry haha.... It's actually another attribute, but it contains some identifying information so I changed it without thinking!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of arrays and you would like to sort them for the first item do like this.

```
var arr = [[7,2],[3,4],[8,5],[4,5],[2,4],[1,2]],
    res = arr.sort((p,c) => p[0]<=c[0] ? -1:1);
```

In your case you probably have to do like below if it is the `href` property of the `a` element you would like to sort for. Or you may replace `href` with `innerText` or `firstChild.nodeValue` if you want to sort for the text inside.

```
Array.prototype.sort.call(liList, (p,c) => p.querySelector('a').href <= c.querySelector('a').href ? -1 : 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.sort.call(liList[someIndex].querySelectorAll('a[href]'), function (a, b) {
        if (a > b) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (a < b) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
```

Above code should sort your elements based on href element of your anchors inside li tags. However, you must note that it won't replace your elements in the order you're expecting unless you write a code to replace based on your sorting.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the most efficient, but I got working.

- Collect the `<a>` into a NodeList with `querySelectorAll()`
- Convert NodeList into an array with `Array.prototype.map.call()`
- And `map` the array with a function that get's each `href`.
- Next a new array of `href`s is populated.
- Then finally is sorted alphabetically by `sort()`

### Snippet

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>36614594</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="http://google.com/">Google</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/">MDN</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://msn.com/">MSN</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://att.net/">AT&amp;T</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var linkArray = [];
    var anchorList = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    var anchorArray = Array.prototype.map.call(anchorList, function(obj) {
      var xHref = obj.href;
      return linkSort(linkArray, xHref);
    });

    function linkSort(list, obj) {

      list.unshift(obj);
      list.sort();
      return list;
    }
    console.log(linkArray);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```